# PLC4x docker container connection timeout to PLC

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-plc4x, plc4x

We've been trying to connect to a PLC but it's not working. We used the basic example "hello-world-plc4x" with JAVA from the  [PLC4x Github repo](https://github.com/apache/plc4x). 
When we start the PLC4x from the console 
 `java -jar .\plc4j-datacare-plc4x-0.9.1-uber-jar.jar --connection-string s7://10.250.46.28 --field-addresses %DB67:10:INT[1]` 
 it's working but as soon as we build the container an start running the container it is not working because of the timeout error as you can see in the Docker log file:

[Connection timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hFVY.png)

Can someone help us to fix the issue or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your error logs indicate some issues with https://netty.io/ (the library we are using in the Java implementation) can you test Docker + Netty to narrow the error down? Additionally it helps us when these kinds of topics occur to write to our mailing list as well 

Comment: If you run a docker container then it is isolated from host network. In order to have access to entire network you need to run container with `--network host`. Otherwise you will end up with internal network which is shared between docker daemon and host.